# Handling scales(maps) when the scale isn't 1:x

Tags: geometry

I tried using Google Maps to get scales and measure the distance(for an assignment). What I find weird is that I get 1.7:100000000 as the scale(1.7cm to 100 million cm, or 1000km)

Using the native google measuring tool, I get that the distance between the two points I am looking at is 8424.54km.

The length of the line is 15 cm

But if I do the normal equation for scales(which in this case is `100000000*15`) I get the wrong number after converting from cm(the current state)to km.

So how do I do the scale calculations when it isn't 1:x, but instead 1.y:x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working in centimetres: $15 \times \dfrac{10^8}{1.7} \approx 880000000$ cm

i.e.  about $8800000$ m or about $8800$ km

Comment: This did the trick, I get the calculations in km to be very close to the measurements Google Maps did.

Answer (score 0):

You want to solve $$\frac{r}{s}=\frac{1}{x}$$

where $r:s$ is the given ratio. The solution is $$x=\frac{s}{r}$$

So, in the above example, simplay divide $10^8$ by $1.7$ to get the desired result.

Comment: So, $1cm$ is about $588,2km$ in reality